# Не получается в Swift добавить ячейки в Table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

У меня есть `UITableView`. Я пытаюсь вывести ячейки первой и единственной секции задав их значения динамически. Вот мой контроллер:

```
import UIKit

class SettingsController: UITableViewController {

    var sections = [10, 15, 30]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("minutesIntervalCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(sections[indexPath.row])
    return cell
    }
}
```

Вот, что у меня в Main.stroyboard:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При открытии этой вьюхи такая ошибка:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Я так понимаю тут проблема в том, что в самой вьюхе только одна ячейка, а я пытаюсь задать три, но я же в коде говорю, что ячеек будет три, а он такое ощущение, что всё равно считает, что ячейка только одна.

Я уже волосы на себе рву, что делать. Пожалуйста помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что у вас в настройках `UITableViewController` в Main.storyboard тип ячеек указан статический, а не динамический. Проверьте этот момент.

Кроме того, существует два метода для создания ячеек: `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("minutesIntervalCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)` попытается создать ячейку, не проверяя наличие свободных в кэше. Этот метод требует, чтобы ячейка и идентификатор были зарегистрированы предварительным вызовом метода `tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "minutesIntervalCell")`.

Второй метод `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("minutesIntervalCell")` крайне рекомендован к использованию, т.к., во-первых, проверяет наличие ячеек в кэше, что положительно сказывается на производительности, а, во-вторых, не ограничен дополнительными требованиями и возвращает `Optional`.

Comment: Оказалось действительно был указан статический тип. Переправил на динамический и всё стало нормально. Спасибо большое! Какие мелочи иногда становятся адскими испытаниями, когда делаешь что-то впервые.

Answer (score 0):

Ты должен указать в Storyboard, что `DataSource` и `Delegate` твоего `tableView` = твой `ViewController`

Для `UITableViewController` они стоят по умолчанию, но надо проверить не отключил ли ты их.